# MySQL select distinct dateTime. Cant figure this query out

Tags: mysql, distinct

My users answer two different questions, they are added to my answers_table as one row each. I'm trying to count how many users have answered my questions which seems simple at first. Count(*) and divide by 2. YES! But: the users can add new questions as they go, so suddenly there might be three questions, all answers/3 becomes an incorrect number of users if there was two  questions for a while and then three, for example!

Can anyone figure out a query for doing this? So far I've got

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT date) as totNum FROM login_answers
```

But it doesn't take the time in consideration. Meaning i just get the amount of answers in total for that day, not knowing how many questions was available that day.

Here's my table:

qid is the QuestionID so i guess thats somewhere to start?

```
id      qid answer  date                deviceID
1502    2   2       2012-10-19 08:42:41 7
1503    1   3       2012-10-19 08:51:53 7
1504    2   2       2012-10-19 08:51:53 7
1505    1   4       2012-10-19 09:05:23 7
1506    2   2       2012-10-19 09:05:23 7
1507    1   4       2012-10-19 09:40:59 7
```

Comment: What does the table of questions look like?  Do you record the date/time each question was added?  How do you decide whether a user should answer a newly added question?  If it's there when they begin?  If it's there when they post their last answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposed solution would be to store a session Id or some auto-generated key against the answers to uniquely identify a "session" of 2, 3 or more answers from a single person.

The query would simply be

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT session_id) totNum
FROM login_answers
```

With your current schema with no identifiable key, it's quite hard to answer your question correctly if at all possible.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing!